# Dynamical height of a block (minimum and maximum height)

Tags: xsl-fo

I am struggling with the dynamical height of an XSL-FO `block element`. I have specified a page layout which contains three main tables. The size of the first table may vary. Therefore I want the last table also to vary in it's height, as I want to fill all the space that's available on the page.
I can specify the minimum as well as the maximum size that the block contained in table #3  can take up. At the same time the content of the third box has to get stripped-down if it's too long for the available space.

My code so far:

```
<fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-cell xs:use-attribute-sets="cell-style font-size-small">
        <fo:block padding-top="3pt" padding-bottom="3pt">
            <fo:inline font-weight="bold">Label:</fo:inline>
        </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>

    <fo:table-cell xs:use-attribute-sets="cell-style font-size-small" >
        <fo:block-container overflow="hidden" min-height="2.1cm" max-height="4cm" padding-top="3pt" padding-bottom="3pt">
            <fo:block height="100%" keep-together.within-page="always">
                <xs:value-of select="$notes"/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:block-container>
    </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. I didn't manage to avoid a page break with this block/table while at the same time display as much text ($notes) as possible.

Your help is much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is here where you state as a requirement:

> I want to fill all the space that's available on the page

Such a concept is not available in XSL-FO 1.x.  There is no semantic "from here to end of page only".  There is no feedback loop to the transformation with which to pass length information of what room is left on a page.

When using XSL-FO you have to blindly use the XSL-FO semantics available to you when you create the XSL-FO file, throw it over the fence to the formatter, then let the formatter deal with your data and the contingencies you've put into your data to accommodate conditions.

*If* you were dealing with only a single page, then you could put a clipping block container on that page and flow the tables into it and the last table would extend to the bottom of the page, but you wouldn't get a border edge at the bottom and the block container would not flow with content before and after the tables.

If the behaviour you want is to be flowed with the rest of the content of your document, then I think you are stuck.

Comment: Indeed, I do deal with only a single page. I think I managed to get your 'solution' that's using the clipping block container, but the result is not the desired one. 
I am aware that there's no "fill all the available space"-function, if I can not specify this remaining space. But I am able to specify the minimum(2cm)/maximum(4cm) available space. Shouldn't this be enough? Isn't there any possibility to define something like "There's a minimum space of 2 cm available and a maximum of 4 cm. If it's possible, use the maximum, otherwise shrink but use at least the minimum - but avoid page break"?

Comment: I'll say it again, "no, there is no such concept in XSL-FO 1.x".  Since you have only one page then the clipping suggestion I gave you should do the trick.  If you need a table border at the bottom, then mimic one by adding the border to the containing block container.  When I teach XSL-FO I remind students what the spec states:  it is flow based.  The table will be as long as the flow.  As you say, it can have a minimum size and it can have a maximum size, but the actual size will be determined by the flow, not by your dimensions.  Simple. But nowhere does it "stretch". Does that makes sense?

Comment: Is there such a "stretch" notion in XSL-FO 2.x perhaps ?

Comment: There is no XSL-FO 2.x ... the W3C established the Page and Print Layout Committee at https://www.w3.org/community/ppl/ to consider whether or what the future of XSL-FO holds.  No conclusions have yet been published by this group.

Answer (score 2):

While this is not pure XSL FO, I have implemented a solution like that using RenderX's software. The solution involves formatting the page as is to the area tree which is an XML structure with all the details of the page including text locations. Using a special extension (which is the rx:pinpoint element) the source XSL FO includes these markers wherever you wish to feather the content.

The original document uses colors placed in the flow and footer area to calculate the space available on the page.

All this information is then available in the area tree. Using XSL to modify the area tree, one can "measure" the available white space, divide by the number of feathering pinpoints and then modify the area tree to "move" the content post composition but before final output. Most all of the formatters allow you to modify the serialized area tree and then give it back to the software for final output.

The key in the below is knowing the xep:translate element which can be used to move all subsequent content in the area tree down. So to "nudge" all the areas, one just inserts one of these at every allowed "nudge" point to move the content down by (available white space/number of nudge points).

I do not know what formatter you are using, but if it is not RenderX, perhaps you can modify the below to suit your needs. This is actually used in several applications, the purpose of which is to "feather" all pages so that the text content of the page ends at the end of a page, always.

Links to samples:

http://www.tandesa.com/Public/Nudge/sf-orig.pdf (this is the original file that would be created if no nudging was applied)

http://www.tandesa.com/Public/Nudge/sf-nofeather.pdf (this shows what it would look like if you output the area tree before nudging, normally not done but it shows how the red/blue areas are used for calculating available nudge area)

http://www.tandesa.com/Public/Nudge/sf-nudged.pdf (the result of nudging)

http://www.tandesa.com/Public/Nudge/nudge.xsl (the file below for completeness)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xep="http://www.renderx.com/XEP/xep" xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math"
extension-element-prefixes="math" version="1.0">
<xsl:param name="max-feather-percent">40</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="body-color" select="'1.0'"/>
<xsl:param name="footer-color" select="'1.0'"/>
<xsl:template match="xep:document">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="identity-copy"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xep:internal-bookmark">
    <xep:internal-bookmark>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="identity-copy"/>
    </xep:internal-bookmark>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xep:page">
    <xep:page>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="identity-copy"/>
        <!--
            1) Figure out white space
                a) Extract the y-till of the footer-color rectangle
                b) Find the smallest y-till of the body-color rectangle
                c) (b) - (a) is white space
        -->
        <xsl:variable name="headertop"
            select="number(xep:rectangle[preceding-sibling::xep:rgb-color[1][@red=$footer-color]]/@y-till)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="pagebottom"
            select="math:min(xep:rectangle[preceding-sibling::xep:rgb-color[1][@red=$body-color]]/@y-from)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="whitespace" select="$pagebottom - $headertop"/>
        <!-- 
            2) Count the nudge areas

            The nudge areas are all the pinpoints that start with "feather" *except* the first one on the page
            and possibly the last one (need to determine it a nudge ends the page then exclude it also)
            <xep:pinpoint x="90000" y="966000" value="feathersection"/>

            Current implementation only ignores the first one and not the last
        -->
        <xsl:variable name="nudgepoints"
            select="count(xep:pinpoint[starts-with(@value,'feather')]) - 1"/>
        <!-- 
            3) Calculate the nudge factor for each                
        -->
        <xsl:variable name="nudgefactor" select="$whitespace div $nudgepoints"/>
        <!-- 
            4) Determine whether the page should be feathered at all 
                a) No nudgepoints
                b) Space to compensate for is greater than max-feather-percent
        -->
        <xsl:variable name="apply-nudge">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$nudgepoints = 0">
                    <xsl:text>false</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="($whitespace div @height) > ($max-feather-percent div 100)">
                    <xsl:text>false</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:text>true</xsl:text>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>

        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:comment> 
            headertop: <xsl:value-of select="$headertop"/>
            pagebottom: <xsl:value-of select="$pagebottom"/>
            nudgepoints: <xsl:value-of select="$nudgepoints"/>
            nudgefactor: <xsl:value-of select="$nudgefactor"/>
            headertop: <xsl:value-of select="$headertop"/>
            pagebottom: <xsl:value-of select="$pagebottom"/>
            applynudge: <xsl:value-of select="$apply-nudge"/>
        </xsl:comment>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="identity-copy">
            <xsl:with-param name="nudgepoints" select="$nudgepoints"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="nudgefactor" select="$nudgefactor"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="apply-nudge" select="$apply-nudge"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xep:page>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Replace proper pinpoints with xep:transform -->

<xsl:template match="xep:pinpoint[starts-with(@value,'feather')]" mode="identity-copy">
    <xsl:param name="nudgepoints"/>
    <xsl:param name="nudgefactor"/>
    <xsl:param name="apply-nudge"/>
    <xsl:if test="count(preceding-sibling::xep:pinpoint[starts-with(@value,'feather')]) > 0 and $apply-nudge = 'true'">
        <xep:translate x="0">
            <xsl:attribute name="y">
                <xsl:value-of select="-1 * $nudgefactor"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xep:translate>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xep:pinpoint[starts-with(@value,'dontfeather')]" mode="identity-copy">
    <xsl:param name="nudgepoints"/>
    <xsl:param name="nudgefactor"/>
    <xsl:param name="apply-nudge"/>
    <xsl:if test="count(preceding-sibling::xep:pinpoint[starts-with(@value,'dontfeather')]) = 0 and $apply-nudge = 'true'">
        <xep:translate x="0">
            <xsl:attribute name="y">
                <xsl:value-of select="$nudgepoints * $nudgefactor"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xep:translate>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Strip out the colored boxes -->
<xsl:template match="xep:rgb-color[@red='{$body-color}']" mode="identity-copy"/>
<xsl:template match="xep:rgb-color[@blue='{$footer-color}']" mode="identity-copy"/>
<xsl:template match="xep:rectangle[preceding-sibling::xep:rgb-color[1][@red='{$body-color}']]" mode="identity-copy"/>
<xsl:template match="xep:rectangle[preceding-sibling::xep:rgb-color[1][@blue='{$footer-color}']]" mode="identity-copy"/> 

<!-- identity copy rules -->
<xsl:template match="node() | @*" mode="identity-copy">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="identity-copy"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="identity-copy"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```